# Pygame is displaying 10x10 grid of different colored squares as black

Tags: python, pygame

I need help with a pygame project I'm doing. Right now it is just supposed to display a 10x10 grid of different colored squares, however it just displays black. It doesn't give me any error messages.

Here is my code, could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
import random, sys, copy, os, pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()


FPS = 30 

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GRAY = (147, 147, 147)
ORANGE = (255, 165, 0)
BGCOLOR = BLACK
TEXTCOLOR = WHITE

DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))

UP = 'up'
DOWN = 'down'
LEFT = 'left'
RIGHT = 'right'

FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()

#Pygame works where the graph has no negative
#The Y axis also starts at 0 ON TOP then GOES DOWN
XMAPCORD = 0
YMAPCORD = 0

def drawWall():
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, BLACK, (XMAPCORD, YMAPCORD, 40, 40), 0)
def drawStone():
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, GRAY, (XMAPCORD, YMAPCORD, 40, 40), 0)
def drawGoal():
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, ORANGE, (XMAPCORD, YMAPCORD, 40, 40), 0)

pygame.display.set_caption('Dungeon Escape')
currentLevel = [
        'w','w','w','w','g','g','w','w','w','w',
        'w','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','w',
        'w','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','w',
        'w','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','w',
        'w','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','w',
        'w','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','w',
        'w','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','w',
        'w','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','w',
        'w','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','s','w',
        'w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w'
]

playerPosition = currentLevel

for i in range(0,100):
    if currentLevel[i] == 'w':
        drawWall()
        XMAPCORD = XMAPCORD + 40
    if currentLevel[i] == 's':
        drawStone()
        XMAPCORD = XMAPCORD + 40
    elif currentLevel[i] == 'g':
        drawGoal()
        XMAPCORD = XMAPCORD + 40
    if XMAPCORD == 400 and YMAPCORD == 0:
        break
    elif i % 10 == 0:
        YMAPCORD = YMAPCORD + 40
        XMAPCORD = 0

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.display.quit()
            sys.exit()

FPS = 30
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = True
while fps:
    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)

pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: You haven't given much information here. What is it producing vs what you expect it to produce? And have you debugged it?

Comment: I want it to produce a set of 10x10 multicolored tiles, the list is what it should look like, however when ran it only shows a black screen. As for debugging IDLE says there are no errors, I am still new to pygameand would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your whole program is stuck in the first `while` loop since it has no way of breaking out. As you can see:

```
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.display.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

The only way to leave, is to exit.

What you should do instead is to combine both of your `while` loops.

```
running = True
FPS = 30
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.display.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Side note: it's not recommended to call `sys.exit()` in the middle of your script with pygame. You should instead change it to `running = False` to let the program exit normally.

Another side note: you don't need two fps clock. Get rid of the first one: `FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()`. And that `playerPosition = currentLevel` is not useful since nowhere in your code uses it.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I know why the display is not working. I appreciate your help.